# Bash match lines from two files

Tags: bash, match, lines

i have two files:

File_1.txt

```
PROCESS1 1234
PROCESS2 1235
PROCESS3 1236
PROCESS4 1237
```

File_2.txt

```
1.2.3.4 1234
1.2.3.5 1235
1.2.3.6 1236
1.2.3.7 1234
1.2.3.8 1234
1.2.3.9 1235
1.2.3.8 1234
1.2.3.8 1234
```

The first file, has a process name and it's pid, and the second file, has an IP and a PID too..
what i need is to find the matching PID from the first file in the second file, and output somenthing like this

Desired_output.txt

```
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.4 1
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.8 3
PROCESS2 1235 1.2.3.5 1
PROCESS2 1235 1.2.3.9 1
PROCESS3 1236 1.2.3.6 1
PROCESS4 1237  - 0
```

Where, the first column is the process name, the second column is the PID , the third column are the ips in the file and the fourth column is the times that the ip is listed in the file_2.txt

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'd get more responses if you tagged this question with something more specific than just `match` and `lines`. Edit: I see from the *title* that this is a bash question, but you really ought to add the `bash` tag.

Comment: suggestion accepted!thought i'd did it thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `join` (who is probably the best solution) :

```
$ join -j2 <(sort -k2 test1.txt) <(sort -k2 test2.txt)
1234 PROCESS1 1.2.3.4
1234 PROCESS1 1.2.3.7
1234 PROCESS1 1.2.3.8
1234 PROCESS1 1.2.3.8
1234 PROCESS1 1.2.3.8
1235 PROCESS2 1.2.3.5
1235 PROCESS2 1.2.3.9
1236 PROCESS3 1.2.3.6
```

Then you could try something like :

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

file1=test1.txt
file2=test2.txt

joinOutput=$(join -j2 <(sort -k2 "$file1") <(sort -k2 "$file2"))
countOutput=$(echo "$joinOutput"|awk '{key=$2" "$1" "$3; if(key in t){t[key]=t[key]+1} else {t[key]=1}} END {for (l in t){print l" "t[l]}}'|sort)
echo "$countOutput"
cat "$file1" <(echo "$countOutput")|cut -d " " -f2|sort|uniq -u|while read; do
    echo "$REPLY - 0"
done
$ ./test.sh
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.4 1
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.7 1
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.8 3
PROCESS2 1235 1.2.3.5 1
PROCESS2 1235 1.2.3.9 1
PROCESS3 1236 1.2.3.6 1
1237 - 0
```

Otherwise, you could try something like :

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

file1=test1.txt
file2=test2.txt

joinOutput=$(
    while read c11 c12; do
        while read c21 c22; do
            [[ $c22 = $c12 ]] && echo "$c11 $c12 $c21"
        done < "$file2"
    done < "$file1"
)

countOutput=$(echo "$joinOutput"|awk '{if($0 in t){t[$0]=t[$0]+1} else {t[$0]=1}} END {for (l in t){print l" "t[l]}}'|sort)
echo "$countOutput"
cat "$file1" <(echo "$countOutput")|cut -d " " -f2|sort|uniq -u|while read; do
    echo "$REPLY - 0"
done
$ ./test.sh
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.4 1
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.7 1
PROCESS1 1234 1.2.3.8 3
PROCESS2 1235 1.2.3.5 1
PROCESS2 1235 1.2.3.9 1
PROCESS3 1236 1.2.3.6 1
1237 - 0
```

Comment: Using process substitution and sorting the files before passing to `join` is a good idea, but you're not sorting by the correct field. You need to do `sort -k2` so that it sorts each file by the PID field.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `join` command, it let's you do exactly that.

Only restriction I can think of, is that the files must be sorted. So if you don't care about preserving the order of the output lines you can use `join`.

Manual page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/join